# Sample=[set of random variables | set of numbers]

Tags: mathematical-statistics, random-variable, sample

I really think I don't understand what a sample really is. All the definitions I came up say that a (random) sample

> $X=(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)$

, where $X_j$ are random variables. So far, so good. But when a sample is given into a problem, it is given as follows:

> $X=(1,34,2,5,1,23,3,4,5)$

a sequence of numbers. How come? I read that a sample should not be confounded by the realization of it, but how can we do that if every single problem I ran into is talking about samples as a sequence of numbers, and not as a sequence of random variables?

Comment: Consider an analogy: what is a frog?  After you contemplate possible definitions and choose one to your liking, find an actual frog.  Is it the same kind of thing as your definition?  *Of course not*.  A definition is a model or a description whereas a frog is a living thing.  Allow me now to paraphrase: "How come ... every single biologist I run into is working with frogs and not with 'a diverse and largely carnivorous group of short-bodied, tailless amphibians composing the order Anura'?"

Comment: But wouldn't it be more intuitive if the definition of a sample were 'a sequence of numbers'? I said numbers, not some concrete numbers.

Comment: What I mean is that I am OK with the following: definition frog - frog; number - 5; random variable - a concrete random variable (the height). The last part I don't see it in theory and problems. What I see is 'random variable' - 5. I can't get it as long as I know that a random variable is a FUNCTION and 5 is a NUMBER.